# Wrapping code in a Class Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a python beginner and I want to wrap my code in a class. However when I run the code I am getting an AttributeError: 'Generating_objects' object has no attribute 'pick_type'. Please tell me where is wrong ?

```
import random
from random import choice

class Generating_objects(object):
      """This class would be used to generate objects of different types e.g 
          integers, string, lists and so on"""


    def __init__(self):
        pass



    def generateRandomInt(self):
        self.num = random.randint(-100000, 1000000000)
        return self.num



    def pick_type(self):

       lists = ["Int","String","Float","bool"]

       choices = choice(lists)


       if choices == "Int":
          print generateRandomInt()
       else:
          print "BOO"

genR = Generating_objects()
genR.pick_type()
```

Comment: Does the indentation above match what is in your code?

Comment: Then hit the `edit` button, copy paste your code there again, select the code, then click the `{ }` button on the toolbar. ;)

Comment: The code in your question cannot match the code you're running. The code from your question would give an **IndentationError**.

Comment: Did you try to leave out the init declaration? I guess, the `pass` breaks initialising even the parent `object` class, so your class has no attributes at all

Comment: I tried your code - it doesn't throw an error, just prints BOO

Comment: My indenting the code was just wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Python is indentation-sensitive. Your methods need to be indented inside the class (ie further than the class declaration):

```
class Generating_objects(object):
  """This class would be used to generate objects of different types e.g 
      integers, string, lists and so on"""

  def __init__(self):
    pass
    ...

  def pick_type(self):
    ...
```

Comment: your code also has an indentation error - """docstrings""" must also be indented on the same level as the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in your code is not correct. Check this link for reference.
[Python: I'm getting an 'indented block' error on the last 3 quotes (""") of my comments under functions. What's up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755566/python-im-getting-an-indented-block-error-on-the-last-3-quotes-of-my-c)